# if statement not running in the while loop in python

Tags: tic-tac-toe

I encountered a problem while running some code for taking input in the TicTacToe game. The code is written as below:

```
def player_input():
marker = " "

while marker != "X" and marker != "O":
    marker = input("Player 1: Do you want me to play X or O? ").upper()

if marker == "X":
    return ("X", "O")
else:
    return ("O", "X")
```

player_input()

After calling the function, the 'if loop' does not run here in the text editor, whereas in the Jupyter notebook, the code returns the tuple, I can't understand why! Need help. I am a beginner.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and fixing your indentation?  What you have written now isn't valid syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the line indentations..And you didnt mention the method outside the code..

Line Indentations:
In simple terms indentation refers to adding white space before a statement. But the question arises is it even necessary?
To understand this consider a situation where you are reading a book and all of a sudden all the page numbers from the book went missing. So you don’t know, where to continue reading and you will get confused. This situation is similar with Python. Without indentation, Python does not know which statement to execute next or which statement belongs to which block.

Revised version of code....

```
def player_input():
    marker = "  "
    while marker != "X" and  marker != "O":
        marker = input("Player do you want to play X or O").upper()
        if marker   == "X":
            print("You have chosen X and if statement works...Insert your command here")
        else:
            print("You have chosen O and else statement works...Insert your command here")
        
player_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the proper spacing for the code. Like this

```
while <condition>:
//Code block
    if <condition>:
        //<statement 1>
    else:
        //<statement 2>
```

Comment: While this is a helpful comment for the OPer, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What do you mean, @Daniel? Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: You're correct that his indentation is wrong.  However, that must be just how he typed it into StackOverflow and not how it's actually written in his code.  Otherwise, he'd be receiving a `SyntaxError`.  Therefore, the correction, while good and necessary, doesn't address why his actual code isn't working.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thanks @DanielWalker

Comment: You know what?  I’m being too picky.  Ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing indentations, after adding proper indentations the following code returns a touple :

```py
def player_input():
    marker = " "

    while marker != "X" and marker != "O":
        marker = input("Player 1: Do you want me to play X or O? ").upper()

    if marker == "X":
        return ("X", "O")
    else:
        return ("O", "X")
```